# Regex to replace multiple blank lines

Tags: regex

Why does the following pattern not match only **two or more** consecutive blank lines?
(Including regex flag : **Multiline**)

```
/(^\s*$){2,}/m
```

Using [Regex101](https://www.regex101.com/#pcre), I see that it matches (for example) the first single blank line of example below (note, I did use ALT-255 for the first character in the block quote below just to represent a starting blank line, remove it if you copy the example text):

```
 
 some text after the first blank line
 more text
  // comment after a space


 // comment after 2 blank lines 
 text
 // comment

 // comment
```

How can I tweak this to match 2 or more blank lines only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex you should be using is `^\n{1,}$`

This will look for `2 or more` blank newlines.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zS7bK5/1)**

Comment: yes, that makes sense - I want to match actual new lines (one or more), **between** the start anchor and end anchor (last end of line)

Answer (score 1):

```
  ^(\n{2,})
```

Here is the working [DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/yM9vA1/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to include 2 or more consecutive blank lines *which may or may not have whitespace characters in the lines*:

`(^\s*\n{2,})`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y0qRze/1)